# Looking for specific element in a 2d array

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

So I have a project where one part of the systems sent a 2d array to Processing. From there Processing looks through the array and plays a sound if certain numbers are in the array. I was wondering if there was a way to loop throught and look for a specific element in the array. Current code is below an example of what I want to do. Also should I just make this a class instead of looping?

What I want: Int[][] x = {1,{3,2,4},2}. Processing pings if it sees a 2 and pongs if it sees a 1.

```
int [][] loops = {{1},{3,2,4},{1}};

void mousePressed()
{
  for (int i =0; i < loops.length;i++)
  {
    println("i = " + i);
    for (int j = 0; j < loops[i].length; j++)
    {
    println("j = " + j);
    if (loops[i][j] == 1) 
    {
     delay(1500);
     println("silence " + j) ;
    }    
    if (loops[i][j] == 2);
    {
      song2.rewind();          // Rewind sounds for future playback
      int y = millis();        // Temp Variable 
      song2.play();            // Self Explanitory
      delay(song2.length()); 
      println("dingdong " + j);
     }
    if (loops[i][j] == 3) 
    {
    println("Start Loop");
    }
   }
  }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You could just make a very simple method for searching through an array and use that in your code.  For example

```
public static boolean hasInt (int[][] list, int input)
{
    for(int i=0;i<list.length;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<list[i].length;j++)
        {
            if(list[i][j]==input)
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Also you should really indent after using an open brace { or any time you make a loop or conditional because it would make your code more readable. Also instead of having a bunch of `if`s use `else if`. The `else if` will be skipped entirely if a previous conditional has been met and since in your code you are checking for different things like an int equaling 1, 2, or 3 then at max only one of those can be true. Therefore there is no point if checking if the rest of them are true.

Comment: Awesome I'll do that. I do have everything indented, I just messed up transposing it from Processing to Stack.